# "Chocolate- and vanilla-flavored cookies" » Using a hyphenated compound adjective in a list of only two items (as opposed to three)

Tags: grammar

This is what distinction I'm trying to draw by applying a hyphenated compound adjectives list of two, as opposed to the usual three.

> **1. "The vanilla and chocolate flavored cookies."**
>
> *There are vanilla-only cookies and chocolate-only cookies.*

> **2. "The vanilla- and chocolate-flavored cookies."**
>
> *There are cookies which contain both vanilla and chocolate.*

What is this type of hyphen usage called?

EDIT I: I believe the structure is a type of Hyphenated Compound Adjectives List. [Englishgrammar101.com](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-6/modifiers-adjectives-and-adverbs/lesson-3/compound-adjectives) (I make no claims as to its reliability) claims,

> Definition: A compound adjective is made up of two or more words put together. Some adjectives are compound. Some are written as one word (closed) and some are hyphenated. Few are written as two words (open).
> Hyphenated compounds usually occur when the writer wants to be clear that the first adjective is modifying the second, not that both adjectives are modifying the noun. If the sentence is written with the adjectives as predicate adjectives, they are often not hyphenated.

and later,

> **Hyphenated adjectives in a list**
> If you use two or more hyphenated adjectives in a list, you can suspend the hyphen. For example:
>
> > I like vanilla-, strawberry-, and chocolate-flavored ice cream.

Edit II: DM_with_secrets is correct. My updated example didn't make sense with the existing apple comparison. I've updated the example.

Comment: I've never seen this before. Do you have a source for it?

Comment: I don't know. I'd read the second one as the apple is simultaneously all red and all blue. More appropriate if you had a bowl filled with a mix of red and blue apples.

Comment: I would assume it was a typo.  The structure looks ungrammatical to me.

Comment: There was a typo in my title. Updated!

Comment: Your edit is describing a different situation. In the ice cream example, 'vanilla-' is short for 'vanilla-flavored'. The hyphen isn't just because you have a list of items, it's because the items are already hyphenated and you just want to not repeat the 'flavored' part. That doesn't apply to your apple example at all.

Comment: I've never seen this before - but it is a good question and I don't know the answer as to how it should be written. My inclination would be to write ***...the vanilla and chocolate-flavoured ice-cream***. I suppose you could write it as ***...the vanilla-and-chocolate-flavoured ice-cream*** but it seems a bit heavy-handed.